# I want to pass variable which dont have a value always

Tags: php, arrays, page-curl

I am getting json data. I decode that data and echo inside the table. I am using url to pass the arrays  from the selected row. My problem is, there is a variable which  is don't have value always. how can i put condition when i have value i want to pass

here is my code

```
echo '<td ><a href="sessiondetails.php?'.htmlentities(http_build_query(array('docname'=>$key['DocName'],'HosName'=>$key['HosName'],'HosCode'=>$key['HosCode'],'SpecialitionID'=>$key['SpecializationId'],'DoctorNo'=>$key['DoctorNo'],'day'=>$key['AppDay'],'date'=>$key['AppDate'],'SpecName'=>$key['SpecName'],'town'=>$key['HosTown'],'DoctorNotes'=>$key['DoctorNotes'])),ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED,'UTF-8',true).'">More>></a></font></td></tr>';
```

this is my error msg when is don't have value

"Undefined index: DoctorNotes"

I don,t have any idea how to solve this.

I am using get method to get the value

```
$DoctorNotes=$_GET ['DoctorNotes'];
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($_GET)` and show us the output?

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

check **isset** before using **$_GET**

```
if(isset($_GET['DoctorNotes']))
{
   $DoctorNotes=$_GET['DoctorNotes'];
} else {
   $DoctorNotes="";
}
```

Or

```
$DoctorNotes= isset($_GET['DoctorNotes'])?$_GET['DoctorNotes']:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value is set, and if it not, set the value of `$doctorNotes` manually and assign it null value, else use the `$_GET` value.

```
if(!isset($_GET['DoctorNotes'])) {
  $doctorNotes = "";
} else {
  $doctorNotes = $_GET['DoctorNotes'];
}
```